# Can't animate Custom View

Tags: android, android-animation

I was creating my textview which use as a header in my MainActivity file and everything was okay until I thought I'd better move the code to another class.
While it works and displays the text however when I try to animate it it doesn't work.
The code I was using is in the init() method.

The code is very simple and I'm pasting it here:

```
public class TextViewHeader extends TextView {
private static final String TAG = "TextViewHeader".toUpperCase();

private Context context;
private FrameLayout frameLayoutWhiteTowerContainer;

private String text;
private int whiteTowerContainerHeight;
private int tower_height;

public TextViewHeader(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public TextViewHeader(Context context, String text, FrameLayout frameLayoutWhiteTowerContainer,
                      int whiteTowerContainerHeight, int tower_height) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.text = text;
    this.frameLayoutWhiteTowerContainer = frameLayoutWhiteTowerContainer;
    this.whiteTowerContainerHeight = whiteTowerContainerHeight;
    this.tower_height = tower_height;
    init();
}

public TextViewHeader(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}


private void init() {
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setText(text);
    textView.setTextSize(25);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF545454"));
    Typeface typefaceCondensed = Typeface.create("sans-serif-condensed", Typeface.BOLD);
    textView.setTypeface(typefaceCondensed);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams tv_header_params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    int topMargin = whiteTowerContainerHeight / 2 - tower_height / 2 - 100;
    tv_header_params.topMargin = topMargin;
    tv_header_params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
    textView.setLayoutParams(tv_header_params);

    frameLayoutWhiteTowerContainer.addView(textView, tv_header_params);
}


}
```

The code in MainActivity is :

```
                tvHeader =  new TextViewHeader(MainActivity.this, "TOWER", flWhiteTowerContainer,
                    whiteTowerContainerHeight, tower_height ); // create inside onCreate method  
                    tvHeader.animate().y(515).setDuration(1500).start(); //and the animation happens later onMapReady
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that  I'm implementing the TextView but I don't use it. Instead I just create another TextView in the class and I use this instead of my class.

In other words the code :

```
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
```

shouldn't exist and just use `this` to setText, setTextSize, color, etc.

```
    this.setText(text);
    this.setTextSize(25);
    this.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF545454"));
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you can't do this `this = new TextView(context);`

Comment: Yes you are right. I pasted the code in pastebin if you want to check it.
http://pastebin.com/hAgt0S2v

Answer (score 0):

You are starting an animation before the TextViewHeader is laid out.

Try:

```
tvHeader = new TextViewHeader(MainActivity.this, "TOWER", flWhiteTowerContainer,
                    whiteTowerContainerHeight, tower_height );    
tvHeader.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreDraw() {
                    // Layout complete but not drawn yet
                    tvHeader.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                    tvHeader.animate().y(515).setDuration(1500).start();
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Animation starts way later. I can also see the text displayed correct on screen. I tried your code but nothing seems to change.

Comment: I don't think anything is wrong in your custom view. Can you show more of the activity? Are you animating the tvHeader elsewhere too? (Because  `view.animate()` uses the same `ViewPropertyAnimator` and doesn't reset previous values)

Comment: Is there a reason why you are creating the tvHeader in a posted runnable?

Comment: I have to wait for flWhiteTowerContainer's height to get a value and then flWhiteTowerContainer to get ready so I can attach the headerview to it.

Comment: I just removed the runnable code and the view doesnt appears at all

Comment: Yeah, I get that. Why not do it in the GlobalLayout listener?

Comment: You are right and I moved it to listener. Still the animation isn't working

Comment: Try `PropertyValuesHolder pvhY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("y", 515);
Animator yAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(tvHeader, pvhY);
yAnim.setDuration(1500);
yAnim.start();`

Comment: I have had issues with `ViewPropertyAnimator` in the past try the prev comment with `ObjectAnimator`

Comment: Hey thanks for your help. I finally figured it out and it was a dummy mistake for me. Check my answer for the solution.